# How to find the View controller name and method name where exactly application crashed in ios?

Tags: objective-c, crash-reports, segmentation-fault, symbolicatecrash

I'm unable to get which causes the application to crash. I'm having binary file and dSYM file along with crash report and I tried different ways (terminal commands) to symbolicate crash log but no luck. Please find the below crash information.

```
Incident Identifier: A6366067-1843-4FA8-8914-501E78105012
CrashReporter Key:
Hardware Model:      iPhone5,1
Process:             CustomerCare [255]
Path:                /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/B5BA73A3-D2B6-427B-83A9-3E8D3DE20932/Appname.app/Appname
Identifier:          com.compName.Appname
Version:             8.0.6
Code Type:           ARM
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2015-10-01 16:22:05 +0000
OS Version:          iPhone OS 8.2 (12D508)
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  SIGSEGV
Exception Codes: SEGV_ACCERR at 0xb000000c
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x35673f46 objc_msgSend (in libobjc.A.dylib) + 6
1   UIKit                               0x2adbaf2d -[UISectionRowData refreshWithSection:tableView:tableViewRowData:] (in UIKit) + 173
2   UIKit                               0x2adbadc1 -[UITableViewRowData rectForFooterInSection:heightCanBeGuessed:] (in UIKit) + 329
3   UIKit                               0x2adbac01 -[UITableViewRowData heightForTable] (in UIKit) + 57
4   UIKit                               0x2adbaa39 -[UITableView _updateContentSize] (in UIKit) + 345
5   UIKit                               0x2adc078b -[UITableView didMoveToWindow] (in UIKit) + 71
6   UIKit                               0x2aceb185 -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] (in UIKit) + 1313
7   UIKit                               0x2ad0a07b -[UIScrollView _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] (in UIKit) + 51
8   UIKit                               0x2aceaef5 -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] (in UIKit) + 657
9   UIKit                               0x2aceaef5 -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] (in UIKit) + 657
10  UIKit                               0x2aceaef5 -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] (in UIKit) + 657
11  UIKit                               0x2acea805 __45-[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:]_block_invoke (in UIKit) + 113
12  UIKit                               0x2acea721 -[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:] (in UIKit) + 429
13  UIKit                               0x2acf4bcf -[UIView(Internal) _addSubview:positioned:relativeTo:] (in UIKit) + 1463
14  UIKit                               0x2acf460f -[UIView(Hierarchy) addSubview:] (in UIKit) + 31
15  UIKit                               0x2aeb9e21 __53-[_UINavigationParallaxTransition animateTransition:]_block_invoke (in UIKit) + 1121
16  UIKit                               0x2acfada5 +[UIView(Animation) performWithoutAnimation:] (in UIKit) + 73
17  UIKit                               0x2aeb977d -[_UINavigationParallaxTransition animateTransition:] (in UIKit) + 813
18  UIKit                               0x2ae77cfd -[UINavigationController _startCustomTransition:] (in UIKit) + 2861
19  UIKit                               0x2ad97027 -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] (in UIKit) + 423
20  UIKit                               0x2ad96e2d -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] (in UIKit) + 45
21  UIKit                               0x2ad96dc1 -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] (in UIKit) + 185
22  UIKit                               0x2aceb7ff -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] (in UIKit) + 515
23  QuartzCore                          0x2a711835 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] (in QuartzCore) + 137
24  QuartzCore                          0x2a70d20d CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*)() (in QuartzCore) + 361
25  QuartzCore                          0x2a70d095 CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*)() (in QuartzCore) + 17
26  QuartzCore                          0x2a70ca71 CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*)() (in QuartzCore) + 225
27  QuartzCore                          0x2a70c875 CA::Transaction::commit()() (in QuartzCore) + 325
28  UIKit                               0x2aced203 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue (in UIKit) + 1443
29  CoreFoundation                      0x27797fbf __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ (in CoreFoundation) + 15
30  CoreFoundation                      0x277973cf __CFRunLoopDoSources0 (in CoreFoundation) + 219
31  CoreFoundation                      0x27795a35 __CFRunLoopRun (in CoreFoundation) + 773
32  CoreFoundation                      0x276e33b1 CFRunLoopRunSpecific (in CoreFoundation) + 477
33  CoreFoundation                      0x276e31c3 CFRunLoopRunInMode (in CoreFoundation) + 107
34  GraphicsServices                    0x2ed10201 GSEventRunModal (in GraphicsServices) + 137
35  UIKit                               0x2ad4d43d UIApplicationMain (in UIKit) + 1441
36  CustomerCare                        0x0022886b 0x6c000 + 1820779
37  libdyld.dylib                       0x35bf3aaf start (in libdyld.dylib) + 3
```